# Send app data to Google Spreadsheet From app Using Retrofit

Tags: android, google-sheets, retrofit

I am trying to send data from an xml form in my app to Google spreadsheet using this tutorial : [[TUT] Send app data to a web spreadsheet (Google Sheets)](http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/tut-send-app-data-to-a-web-spreadsheet-google-sheets/)

After going through the step by step walkthrough, i was able to write data on my google spreadsheet but my app crashes after clicking on Send button.

- The Google form has 3 TextViews and 1 RadioGroup Button with 5 radio
         buttons

**The Error:**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
      Process: com.example.domain, PID: 9839
      java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void okhttp3.Callback.onResponse(okhttp3.Call, okhttp3.Response)"
      at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**questions_activity.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">        

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/question_name_input_hint"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

   <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emergency_type">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/emergency_type_fire"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/type_fire" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/emergency_type_accident"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/type_accident" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/emergency_type_robbery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/type_robbery" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/emergency_type_fight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/type_fight" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/emergency_type_flood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/type_flood" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/emergency_type_others"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/type_other" />

        </RadioGroup>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_emergency"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_emergency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="@string/hint_emergency" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_mobile" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/questions_submit_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:elevation="6dip"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            support:pressedTranslationZ="12dip" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActvity.java:**

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.questions_activity);



        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/")
                .build();
        final QuestionsSpreadsheetWebService spreadsheetWebService = retrofit.create(QuestionsSpreadsheetWebService.class);

        nameInputField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        emergencyTypeSelect = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.emergency_type);
        emergencyInputField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_emergency);
        mobileInputField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input_mobile);
        findViewById(R.id.questions_submit_button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String nameInput = nameInputField.getText().toString();
                        String emergencyType = String.valueOf(emergencyTypeSelect.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                        String emergencyInput = emergencyInputField.getText().toString();
                        String mobileInput = mobileInputField.getText().toString();
                        Call<Void> completeQuestionnaireCall = spreadsheetWebService.completeQuestionnaire(nameInput, emergencyType,emergencyInput, mobileInput);
                        completeQuestionnaireCall.enqueue(callCallback);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private final Callback<Void> callCallback = new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Void> response) {
            Log.d("XXX", "Submitted. " + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e("XXX", "Failed", t);
        }
    };


    }
```

**The Listener: 
 QuestionsSpreadsheetWebService.java**

```
        import retrofit2.Call;
    import retrofit2.http.Field;
    import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
    import retrofit2.http.POST;

    public interface QuestionsSpreadsheetWebService {

        @POST("my_url_endpoint/formResponse")
        @FormUrlEncoded
        Call<Void> completeQuestionnaire(
                @Field("entry.242003698") String name,
                @Field("entry.1813695726") String answerQuestionCat,
                @Field("entry.261820127") String emergency,
                @Field("entry.1790329242") String mobileNo

        );

    }
```

Comment: `@POST("my_url_endpoint/formResponse")` is your real adress or you wanted to hide API key?

Comment: @R.Zagórski No it isn't my real email address, I removed it for security purposes. Thanks

Comment: Are you using stable version of `Retrofit`?
Is your call made in background thread?

Comment: @R.Zagórski  This is the compile library i am using in the project 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'  and call is made in background thread.

Comment: Solutions described [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1475) do no work?

Comment: @R.Zagórski I just tried changing the dependency to the version recommended in on the page, but i got error in my call back `Class 'Anonymous class derived from Callback' must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onResponse(Call <T>, Response <T>)` in Callback" after syncing my project